# How does automatic account association work?

Tags: discussion, openid, linked-accounts

I'm interested in some technical information on how you achieved the [automatic account association as discussed on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/).  What is "the way to make it happen"?   Do you have an (internal) API between your sites where you call out to each of them and ask for information based on the same OpenID, and does this account for the different IDs generated by Google per domain - if so, [using the e-mail method as discussed here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/)?  Is there any magic to this, or is it just automating the previous process?

Comment: Good Luck getting an answer :)